# Need an if statement for X Y coordinates of an HTML5 Canvas with inputs

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I have 4 inputs. Input boxes 2 and 4 are optional. If input box 2 is left empty, I need input 3's X Y coordinates to shift up on the canvas. The reason for the shift is all 4 inputs will draw on the canvas which has a background image with precise locations for each input line of text.

I am unsure of how to use jquery because of the X Y coordinates.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/Canvas2Image.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core-compat.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEventListener('load', function () {
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var oCtx;

        function updateClicked() {
            oCtx.font = "300 32px coleman";     
            oCtx.textBaseline = "top";         
            oCtx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById("line1").value, 253, 122);

            oCtx.font = "500 22px coleman";     
            oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById("line2").value, 253, 166);

            oCtx.font = "300 32px coleman";  
            oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById("line3").value, 253, 422);

            oCtx.font = "500 22px coleman"; 
            oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById("line4").value, 253, 466);
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            var oCanvas = document.getElementById("thecanvas");
            oCtx = oCanvas.getContext("2d");
            var iWidth = oCanvas.width;
            var iHeight = oCanvas.height;
            var img = new Image();

            //oCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
            //oCtx.fillRect(0,0,iWidth,iHeight);
            img.onload = function () {
                oCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            };
            img.src = "nametag.png";
            //BACKGROUND-IMAGE//

            function showDownloadText() {
                document.getElementById("buttoncontainer").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("textdownload").style.display = "block";
            }

            function hideDownloadText() {
                document.getElementById("buttoncontainer").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("textdownload").style.display = "none";
            }

            function convertCanvas(strType) {
                if (strType == "PNG")
                    var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas, true);
                if (strType == "BMP")
                    var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsBMP(oCanvas, true);
                if (strType == "JPEG")
                    var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(oCanvas, true);
                if (!oImg) {
                    alert("Sorry, this browser is not capable of saving." + strType + " files!");
                    return false;
                }
                oImg.id = "canvasimage";

                oImg.style.border = oCanvas.style.border;
                oCanvas.parentNode.replaceChild(oImg, oCanvas);

                showDownloadText();
            }
          //RENDER IMAGE
              document.getElementById("convertpngbtn").onclick = function () {
                convertCanvas("PNG");
            }

            document.getElementById("resetbtn").onclick = function () {
                var oImg = document.getElementById("canvasimage");
                oImg.parentNode.replaceChild(oCanvas, oImg);

                hideDownloadText();
            }

        }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="font-family: coleman; font-weight:300; padding-bottom:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">Test font 1</h1>
    <h4 style="font-family: coleman; font-weight:500; padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;">Test font 2</h4>

    <canvas width="800" height="596" style="border:1px solid black;font-family: coleman;" id="thecanvas"></canvas>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="textdownload" style="display:none;font-style:italic;">
        Right click to save as a transparent PNG or click the edit button below to go back.<br />
        <input type="button" id="resetbtn" class="button" value="EDIT" onclick="window.location.reload()">
    </div>
    <div id="buttoncontainer" style="display:block;">
        <p>
            Line1 :
            <input type="text" style="margin-right:22px;" id="line1" maxlength="50" />
            <input type="text" style="margin-right:22px;" id="line1a" maxlength="50" />
            Line2 :
            <input type="text" name="line2" id="line2" maxlength="50" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Line1 :
            <input type="text" style="margin-right:22px;" id="line3" maxlength="50" />

            Line2 :
            <input type="text" id="line4" maxlength="50" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="button" class="button" id="update" onclick="updateClicked()" value="UPDATE">
             <input type="button" class="button" id="convertpngbtn" value="SAVE">
            <input type="button" id="resetbtn" class="button" value="Reset" onclick="window.location.reload()">
        </p>
    </div>
    <script>
        // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
        if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
            window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
                height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
                slug: "fknjz"
            }], "*")
        }

        // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
        window.name = "result"
    </script>
```

LINE1

LINE2 (optional-if empty Line3's XY shifts up)

LINE3

LINE4 (optional-if empty this final line doesn't show on canvas)

---

**OUTPUT to canvas is:**

Hello my name is Harry

(blank-I am a student shifts up)

I am a student

(blank-space doesn't show on canvas)

---

OR

---

Hello my name is Harry

I live in NY

I am a student

I am 19 years old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG! It just needed to be in an array. My brilliant guru of a co-worker could see it in 10 seconds after reading my code! Thumbs up to him!!!